# How to make sure your code work as expected when processing large data?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I wrote some multithreading batch process to process data.

When I finished implementation and do tests again different set of datas, each has around 100 rows, everything works as expected. But when it actually move to prd, something will fail. Things like deadlock, null pointer exception, datacontraintsvoliation, and wrong output etc.

My question is how to make sure your code works? I did the test with sample data, but I can't really do a test on millions of data, am I right, it is so time consuming? But if I don't do it, my tested code will fail due to some errors which didn't occur during testing.

Is there some sort of practice people use to verify or is it common?

Need some guideline on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen working with big companies and small, all over the world including Silicon Valley, I would say use best practices from the beginning and stick with them, like:

1. know and choose the right technology/language for the job - you can work with C++03 or use Java, GO or Rust and you will have a very different experience
2. have expensive, skillfull programmers in that area and choosen language or skillfull enough to deal with every tech after a certain uptime
3. do not press them to hard or they will create compromises (remember the quality - speed - price triangle)
4. have a serious peer code review culture in the team
5. run static code analysis if available and fix warnings
6. write all the meaningful unit tests (on class/module level, no multi threading on this level, software ideally based on SOLID, testing with mocks)
7. create integration tests (multithreading, real files, real database, real cloud, real scalability here)
8. have a QA department do regression testing under real life conditions with actual hardware setup over and over and over and over ...
9. also let QA and devs test with memory checkers (e.g. valgrind) and/or profiling (depending on language and tech) if possible

It is important to let it run, under real conditions too (aka testing in production... ok let's call it open beta). There attack it with everything you have. This includes all your hacker tools and a horde of wild monkeys.

Even for the biggest companies throwing a mountain of money on their software, there will always be a few remaining hidden bugs or security issues (and known issues to be fixed later maybe). So make sure you have some post mortem procedures when it happens like stacktraces, application logs, system logs, screenshots etc.

In today's software complexity correctness and stability is hellish expensive. For small projects a little less effort might be ok though (depending on the count of casulties, or today more important money loss, in case of a null pointer I would say)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Now I have some clues to know where should I go for our next step,  with these in mind, I can better estimate my work.